# Print arraylist to text file in HUMAN READABLE form

Tags: java, file, arraylist, save

so  i can't figure out how to print an arraylist index (the first index so 0) to a text file. Basically, I have a Job class which stores 5 variables

```
public class Job {

public int teamNo;
    public String regNo;
    public String gridRef;
    public String gridCopy;

    public String toString() {

        return "Job [teamNo=" + teamNo + ", regNo=" + regNo + ", gridRef="
                + gridRef + "";

    }
```

and then I have an arraylist of type Job:

```
private static ArrayList<Job> teamNoOne = new ArrayList<Job>();
```

So the data all gets added fine, prints it out etc but I can't save it to a text file. this is my code, I just get the random hash code of it but I need it in human readable form.

```
try {
                    File file = new File("JOBS-DONE-LOG.txt");
                    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
                    System.out.println(teamNoOne.get(0));

                    os.writeObject(teamNoOne.get(0));
                    os.close();


                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writeObject serializes the object in your file, it doesn't write it in textual form (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject(java.lang.Object))

You must do it in another way: for example, you can use the BufferedWriter class and the write method to write the output of your toString() method.

Here is a complete example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Job {
  public String regNo;
  public String gridRef;
  public String gridCopy;

  public String toString() {

    return "Job [teamNo=" + teamNo + ", regNo=" + regNo + ", gridRef="
    + gridRef + "";

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Job> teamNoOne = new ArrayList<Job>();
    // fill your array
    Job job = new Job();
    job.regNo = "123";
    // continue to fill the jobs...
    teamNoOne.add(job);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("JOBS-DONE-LOG.txt"));
    System.out.println(teamNoOne.get(0));
    writer.write(teamNoOne.get(0).toString());
    os.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: ah, i think I understand what you mean, so if I'm trying to get the toString for the teamNoOne array it'd be something like 

for (Job s : teamNoOne) {
//code to print the index 0 of teamNoOne?
}

Comment: I have updated the post with a complete example to give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've implemented it like that. it prints it out to console fine, but the text file is blank. It accesses it since the last time access changed though

Comment: sorry my mistake, i create the file twice in my code, i update it now. Should be better now :-)

Comment: it works perfectly now! Thanks so much, you are a complete legend!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to save an arraylist of type Job, it has to be serialized ([Refer this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)).

```
  public class Job implements java.io.Serializable
  {
     public int teamNo=0;
     public String regNo="default";
     public String gridRef="default";
     public String gridCopy="default";

    public String toString() {

    return "Job [teamNo=" + teamNo + ", regNo=" + regNo + ", gridRef="
            + gridRef + "";

    }
  }
```

For Saving the file

```
      try
      {
         FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
         out.writeObject(teamNoOne);
         out.close();
         fileOut.close();
      }
      catch(IOException i)
      {
          i.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Thus you can load the arraylist back like

```
      Object o = null;
      try
      {
         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(path);
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
         o = in.readObject();
         in.close();
         fileIn.close();
      }
      catch(IOException i)
      {
          i.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
      {
          c.printStackTrace();
      } 
      Arraylist<Job> loaded_Job = (ArrayList<Job>) o;
```

Then print the arraylist

```
         for(int i = 0; i < loaded_Job.size(); i++) {   
            loaded_Job.get(i).toString();
          }
```

Comment: this still doesn't seem to work. I can only get this as output:

¬í sr Job½u™=læE§ I teamNoL gridCopyt Ljava/lang/String;L gridRefq ~ L regNoq ~ xp   pt aat aa

Comment: What are you using to print ?

Comment: I'm using the ObjectOutputStream to print it out. should be I be using something else?

Comment: I'm talking about printing it to the user not saving to the file.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I can do it now after the serialization? originally I was just going to use a filewriter

Comment: no errors at all, just getting random characters instead of the actual data inside the array

Comment: See the edit, assign default values. Maybe you didnt initialize the variables and what you are seeing may be garbage values.

Comment: ah just saw the edit, thanks for your help so far. I seem to be getting a casting error;

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: Job cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
 at Main$3.actionPerformed(Main.java:314)

Answer (score -2):

This happens because you didn't parameterize your `ArrayList`. Use generics when declaring your list:

```
ArrayList<Job> teamNoOne = new ArrayList<Job>();
```

Because now, though you have overriden your `toString()` method, `teamNoOne.get(0)` uses an `Object`'s `toString()`.

Comment: sorry I'm new to java and a bit confused, how should I go about changing the declaration? I'm getting errors when I remove the private static due to other for methods which rely on it.